# Calculated Column for multiple rows based on single row

Tags: oracle

Consider this data:

```
user    code    score
1       1       50 
1       2       100
2       1       100     
3       2       100 
4       2       50
```

Basically I want to get all the scores for each user, but I want a calculated column based on only rows with a certain code.

So: `CASE WHEN code = 2 AND score > 50 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'`.

But I want the calculated column to ignore the `1` code.

So the results of the data above should be:

```
user    code    score   pass
1       1       50      Yes
1       2       100     Yes
2       1       100     No
3       2       100     Yes
4       2       50      No
```

I'm sure there is some Oracle SQL function to partition the data but I don't know how.

- Row 1: Yes because the same user has 100 in row 2.
- Row 2: Yes because code 2 is > 50.
- Row 3: No because it's a code 1 and they don't have any code 2 scores.
- Row 4: Yes because it's a code 2 > 50.
- Row 5: No because it's a code 2 lower than 51.

Based on @mathguy's answer, I made this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN (sortest_tesc_code = 'A02' AND sortest_test_score >= 23) OR
            (sortest_tesc_code = 'S02' AND sortest_test_score >= 540) OR
            (sortest_tesc_code = 'MPT' AND sortest_test_score >= 60) OR
            (sortest_tesc_code = '66' AND sortest_test_score >= 3) THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY sortest_pidm) = 0 THEN 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
END pass,
```

Checking the data now, but I think this is working.

Comment: I'm confused.  What should "Pass" be when the code is 1?  Null?

Comment: So, you want the result to have as many rows as the input - and not just one row per user? It seems for a given user, the calculated column has the same "pass" in all rows, so it's not clear why you need more than one row per user in the output.

Comment: `CASE WHEN code = 1 or (code = 2 AND score > 50) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END`

Comment: @juergend so user 2 code 1 says no but it's code 1. your's would show yes.

Comment: It looks `code = 1` is populated `Yes` when there was `code = 2 and score > 50` for the same user in other cases it is `No`

Comment: @Kacper - it seems that way, and it's why I asked the OP if he should only get one row per user in the output. :-)

Comment: @xQbert user 2 has no entry for `code = 2` so it is ok

Comment: My guess there is a typo in the sample data, so my suggestion dont go crazy with this one.

Comment: So I need both scores but I want the "pass/fail" to only be calculated on scores from code 1.

Comment: @Leeish That doesnt make sense, You have pass/fail on all rows

Comment: I know I do, I need the pass/fail to take into account  the code 2 scores for the user.

Comment: See my edits, I hope my explanations behind why each row is yes/no makes sense as to what I'm trying to accomplish (if possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for analytic functions. Of course, `user` is a reserved word, so it should not be a column name. Other than that:

```
with
     test_data ( usr, code, score ) as (
       select 1, 1,  50 from dual union all
       select 1, 2, 100 from dual union all
       select 2, 1, 100 from dual union all
       select 3, 2, 100 from dual union all
       select 4, 2,  50 from dual
     )
-- end of test data. Solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select usr, code, score,
       case when count(case when code != 1 and score > 50 then 1 end)
                 over (partition by usr) = 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end as passed
from test_data
;

       USR       CODE      SCORE PASSED
---------- ---------- ---------- ------
         1          1         50 Yes
         1          2        100 Yes
         2          1        100 No 
         3          2        100 Yes
         4          2         50 No
```

Comment: Right I just used basic names for the example because my real tables/name are much longer. It's the analytic functions I'm least familiar with. I try to read up on them, but I use them so infrequently I end up back on SO for help. It's like I know it "can" be done but don't know exactly how. Like I said, I do much more front/back end than at the DB level.

Comment: @Leeish - Analytic functions aren't that complicated - and count() in particular, the analytic version, is even easier to understand. "partition by usr" causes the table to be treated as if it was many small, independent tables, one for each usr. Then, the analytic function will attach a value (in this case, the count) to each row in the input, instead of one value per group or "partition". This is all there is to this specific problem (yours), anyway! Analytic functions in general (even count(), if I had given it an ORDER BY clause in addition to PARTITION BY), but not the case here.

Comment: Right now I'm trying to translate your answer into my actual tables which actually have a few different `code` values I need to use and not use.  I think I got it, testing now, but if not I may need some help. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

still making lots of assumptions... but this results in the output given..

```
with cte as (
Select 1 usr,       1 code,       50 score  from dual union all
Select 1,       2,       100 from dual union all
Select 2,       1,       100 from dual union all     
Select 3 ,      2,       100 from dual union all
Select 4  ,     2,       50 from dual )
Select A.*, case when B.usr is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as pass
from cte A
LEFT JOIN (Select * from cte where code = 2 and score > 50) B
 on A.Usr = B.usr
 order by A.usr, A.code
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution but requires joining the table twice. Sorry I'm less familiar with SQL functions (mainly a front/back end dev not SQL dev). You don't see any built in functions that could help like Partition/Grouping the scores by user or something. I think this will work looking at it actually.

Comment: You can do a grouping, but your final result show all the rows, so still will need a `JOIN`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - no; when you need to do a grouping but the final result shows all rows, you use analytic functions (much more efficient than doing joins).

Comment: Agreed my cost 15, mathguy 11.  Both provide correct results.  I think mine is easier to maintain from a small group learning SQL; his is much more efficient but a little more difficult to grasp if starting new with SQL.

Comment: @xQbert - optimizer cost is not very relevant when comparing plans for different queries (they are used for different execution plans for the same query). For example, analytic functions may use more CPU and take longer for that reason (even though the cost doesn't show that). But for large tables (not the five rows we have here) the difference will be substantial in favor of analytic functions. Agreed though, if this is someone just learning SQL, then they should learn how to do joins first, and your solution is more appropriate.

Comment: @mathguy You've been an acquired taste but I like the way you challenge and educate.  Thanks for pushing back; it's making me better!  Nice Oracle article on why: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:313416745628

Answer (score 0):

```
with userscore (select user, sum(case WHEN code = 2 AND score > 50 then 1 else 0) s end 
                from my_table group by user)
select m.*, CASE WHEN (code = 2 AND score > 50) or (code = 1 and s > 0) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' end
  from my_table m, userscore;
```

Comment: Results in 20 rows once I get the syntax right.  case w/o end on 1st line and use of user reserved word didn't go well w/ compiler.  try `userscore as (select user, sum(case WHEN code = 2 AND score > 50 then 1 else 0 end) s`